# Adding customer tags to order printer template in Shopify

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid

Sorry, I only have a very basic understanding of liquid but I am trying to add customer tags to our printed orders via the Shopify Order Printer app. I have previously edited the template by referring to the liquid variable list but when adding the customer.tags variable it is not returning anything.
The customer.tags variable is not shown in the reference for the order printer template but appears elsewhere so I'm not even sure if I can use in in this template. 
The provided syntax in the reference is

`{% for tag in customers.tags %}
  {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. . thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Customer object within the Order Printer app only gives access to the following 2 properties:

```
{{ customer.name }}
{{ customer.email }}
```

Unfortunately customer tags are not supported within Order Printer.

You can see this by simply adding `{{ customer }}` to your Order Printer template, as it will then output the hash of properties available to you.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to access other customer properties like notes?

Answer (score 0):

Something is fishy about your question. In your loop you are iterating through an object representing **customers**. Note the plural. There is no such thing in an order. An order has a customer, not has many customers. So if you know you have an Order object, you can almost but not always have access to a customer object. And if you do, you can probably iterate the tags since a customer has many tags.

Perhaps you should try things at the highest level and work your way down. Do you have an Order object? Does it have a Customer Object? If yes, does the Customer have tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this in a way with [TagRobot](https://apps.shopify.com/tag-robot). At the same time it adds a tag to your order, it can add a tag to an array that is readable in [Order Printer](https://apps.shopify.com/order-printer). No way to delete that array, but it can be used to pass data on. Very easy to use.

**Updated, I've been playing with this and found other ways to use it***

Tag robot can also be made to add order tags (and Tags that are passed to order printer) based on tags from products in the order. I've been creating $0 products like "replacement order" that I can add when I am making a corrected order that will make a tag that will in turn flag an order to be processed first. I also use Tag Robot to tag orders that have an overnight option selected so it can not only be tagged for a search but the invoice has a large modification on the top to make it obvious what it's for.

In addition I try to get orders for repeat customers out faster when we are backed up in shipping. I do this with TagRobot by tagging the order "VIP" when they have ordered more than 4 times, and that in turn is passed to order printer to make sure we know to prioritize that order, and to toss something cool in for the customer.

This new featured can be paired with a ton of things that TagRobot already does and has improved automation, and order accuracy for us.